# C# Now() Expressed as string in a with month day year hour and meridian

Tags: c#

I have the following code in VBA and wish to convert it to C#

```
Format(Now(), "m-d-yyyy HAM/PM")
```

Being pretty green with C# syntax I used the following [tool](https://converter.telerik.com/)

It gave me the following:

```
Strings.Format(DateTime.Now(), "m-d-yyyy HAM/PM");
```

Visual Studio is telling me `Strings` and `Now` is wrong. 
Please tell me what did I miss here.

Comment: `Now` is a property, not a method. `DateTine.Now` would be correct.

Comment: In addition, it is `string.Format()` or `String.Format()`.

Comment: Last but not least, the whole line looks wrong to me. Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: A good comprenhension of what's going on is one of the best translation tool. Here you have a DateTime, and you want to apply some format to it in c#. So we hit a search engigne with DateTime Format C#

Comment: And btw telerik is for VB.NET <=> C#. And VBA is not VB.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Format(Now(), "m-d-yyyy HAM/PM")` formats the current date & time according to a time format. The equivalent in C# would be transforming it to a string, since formatting a string is a different operation:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy htt")
```

Comment: The out put is "4-28-2020 " on my machine fw 4.7.2